# ffmpeg command line tool remove all metadata information after converting a file codec

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I am converting abc.flac file to abc.mp3 using ffmpeg command line tool. But when abc.mp3 is created all metadata information get clear like artist name , album name etc. all field get empty.
i am using this command 
ffmpeg -i "abc.flac" -acodec mp3 -ab 256 "abc.mp3"

this give me abc.mp3 i also try -map_metadata tag but it is not working
Have you any idea about this 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your complete ffmpeg console output that results from your ffmpeg command.